# Set preferred language for new users in CP in craft 3

Tags: craft3, craft2, user-profile

I have a customer who is admin and creates new users in the backend, so they can have access in the frontend (with this login they see more content than non-logged in users).
After that, these new users don't have access to the control panel to change their language settings.

This was Craft 2 and the admin could set the preferred language, so that the activation emails would be send out in German or French.

[image: craft 2 new user setting]

Now we updated to Craft 3 and this dropdown for the preferred locale is gone.

[image: craft 3 user setting]

How can we now specify the preferred language via the CP for new users?

Do we need to set-up an own custom field, and put this in the system emails field via twig?

Answer (score 1):

In Craft 3 (and 4), the default language for new users can be set using the [`defaultCpLanguage`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#defaultcplanguage) config setting.

It's also possible to define a default locale using the [`defaultCpLocale`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#defaultcplocale) setting (the locale affects how dates and numbers are formatted, and can be defined independently of the language).

Both of these settings need to be defined in your project's `config/general.php` file.

After confirming their account, users can change both of these settings in the control panel, via the "Language" and "Formatting Locale".

Comment: thanks, but was not clear enough in my question, (will update).
User only have access to the frontend, they can not change their settings in the backend. 
So there is no way to define the language for the user-activations emails, for newly created users?